# Json cannot display in ListView

Tags: java, php, android, json

I am trying to following a tutorial get `json` to `ListView`,
this app just shows `Array` in `json`.
When I use the url source from [this site](http://api.learn2crack.com/android/jsonos/), the app works completely
but when I use local data `json` from my database, data not came out in my app.

The in line 99 and 68 (you can see my command in code)

This my code

testing.php

```
<?php
    //Create Database connection
    $db = mysql_connect("localhost","root","root");
    if (!$db) {
        die('Could not connect to db: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    //Select the Database
    mysql_select_db("skripsi",$db);

    //Replace * in the query with the column names.
    $result = mysql_query("select * from maintenance", $db);  

    //Create an array
    $json_response = array( "maintenance" => array());

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
        $row_array['mid'] = $row['mid'];
        $row_array['pid'] = $row['pid'];
        $row_array['status'] = $row['status'];
        $row_array['head'] = $row['head'];
        $row_array['note'] = $row['note'];

        //push the values in the array
        array_push($json_response["maintenance"],$row_array);
    }
    echo json_encode($json_response);
?>
```

This my JSONParse class

```
private class JSONParse extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {  **//LOGCAT NAVIGATE TO THIS LINE**
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        mid = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.mid);
        pid = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.pid);
        status = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.status);
        head = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.head);
        note = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.note);

        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        pDialog.setMessage("Getting Data ...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }
    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {

        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

        // Getting JSON from URL
        JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequestWithoutParams(url);
        return json;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
        pDialog.dismiss();
        try {
            // Getting JSON Array from URL
            maintenance = json.getJSONArray(TAG_OS);   **//LOGCAT NAVIGATE TO THIS LINE**
            for(int i = 0; i < maintenance.length(); i++){
                JSONObject c = maintenance.getJSONObject(i);
                // Storing  JSON item in a Variable
                String mid = c.getString(TAG_MID);
                String pid = c.getString(TAG_PID);
                String status = c.getString(TAG_STATUS);
                String head = c.getString(TAG_HEAD);
                String note = c.getString(TAG_NOTE);
                // Adding value HashMap key => value
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                map.put(TAG_MID, mid);
                map.put(TAG_PID, pid);
                map.put(TAG_STATUS, status);
                map.put(TAG_HEAD, head);
                map.put(TAG_NOTE, note);
                oslist.add(map);
                list=(ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.list);
                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), oslist,
                        R.layout.list_v,
                        new String[] { TAG_MID,TAG_PID, TAG_STATUS, TAG_HEAD, TAG_NOTE}, new int[] {
                        R.id.mid,R.id.pid, R.id.status,R.id.head, R.id.note});
                list.setAdapter(adapter);
                list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                            int position, long id) {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "You Clicked at " + oslist.get(+position).get("name"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

this my JSONObject

```
public JSONObject makeHttpRequestWithoutParams(String url) {
    // Making HTTP request
    try {
        // defaultHttpClient
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }
    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }
    // return JSON String
    return jObj;
}
```

logcat

```
09-16 14:46:30.661    3481-3481/com.example.blackcustomzier.skripsi W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
09-16 14:46:30.791    3481-3481/com.example.blackcustomzier.skripsi W/System.err﹕ org.json.JSONException: No value for android
09-16 14:46:30.791    3481-3481/com.example.blackcustomzier.skripsi W/System.err﹕ at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:354)
09-16 14:46:30.791    3481-3481/com.example.blackcustomzier.skripsi W/System.err﹕ at org.json.JSONObject.getJSONArray(JSONObject.java:548)
09-16 14:46:30.791    3481-3481/com.example.blackcustomzier.skripsi W/System.err﹕ at com.example.blackcustomzier.skripsi.FragmentMaintain$JSONParse.onPostExecute(FragmentMaintain.java:99)
09-16 14:46:30.791    3481-3481/com.example.blackcustomzier.skripsi W/System.err﹕ at com.example.blackcustomzier.skripsi.FragmentMaintain$JSONParse.onPostExecute(FragmentMaintain.java:68)
09-16 14:46:30.791    3481-3481/com.example.blackcustomzier.skripsi W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
09-16 14:46:30.791    3481-3481/com.example.blackcustomzier.skripsi W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
09-16 14:46:30.791    3481-3481/com.example.blackcustomzier.skripsi W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
09-16 14:46:30.791    3481-3481/com.example.blackcustomzier.skripsi W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-16 14:46:30.791    3481-3481/com.example.blackcustomzier.skripsi W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-16 14:46:30.791    3481-3481/com.example.blackcustomzier.skripsi W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
09-16 14:46:30.791    3481-3481/com.example.blackcustomzier.skripsi W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-16 14:46:30.791    3481-3481/com.example.blackcustomzier.skripsi W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
09-16 14:46:30.791    3481-3481/com.example.blackcustomzier.skripsi W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
09-16 14:46:30.791    3481-3481/com.example.blackcustomzier.skripsi W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
09-16 14:46:30.791    3481-3481/com.example.blackcustomzier.skripsi W/System.err﹕ at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

hope someone can help me thanks

Comment: try changing the class name JSONObject.

Comment: Post the errors you get. Also, you probably need to Google some basic debugging because you just asked a similar question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maintenance = json.getJSONArray(TAG_OS);

looks like value of TAG_OS is "android" but in your json object there is no array with the name "android" so first print the json inf the form of string format it using some foramtter and make sure the name of your json array is "android".

try this link to parse your json
http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Comment: I just saw that there is array in json provided by link you provided http://api.learn2crack.com/android/jsonos/ but not sure your local json has array with same name

Comment: great i forgot to change a value of TAG_OS,
after i change the value of TAG_OS to be maintenance, all working completely..
thanks navin